# Disable string escaping (backslash hell)

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I've started using Java regexes and I find I have to write patterns like this (contrived example):

`C:\\\\windows\\\\system\\d+`

to match

`C:\windows\system32`

Is there any way to use java regex without insane amounts of backslashes?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: You could save them in a separate file, then read that in (possibly as a resource).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) (click for documentation)

It treats all meta characters in the passed String as literal characters (but you still must escape backslashes in construction of a String literal). This lets you type `\\` instead of `\\\\` to denote an actual/literal `\` in the regex pattern. But this also means that any other special characters will be interpreted literally as well (such as `\d+` in your example).

But in your example, you could use:
`Pattern.quote("C:\\windows\\system") + "\\d+";`

Test it with this: `System.out.println("C:\\windows\\system32".matches(Pattern.quote("C:\\windows\\system") + "\\d+"));`

Comment: This will still require \\ because \ is still the string escape character. (Also, wtf does StackOverflow use backslashes as escape characters in comments?)